# Call/Firing Foundation JS in a Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, equalizer

Foundation has some JS functions to detect [Media Queries](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript-utilities.html). My question is how to define some functions just Firing in Medium-up media queries?

Exactly I want to firing [Foundation Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) on medium-up or actually stop working on Mobile.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

@parhum,

I am not sure if this is the right approach but you can always remove the `data-equalizer` attribute and add it back on.

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 767px
        $('.row').attr('data-equalizer','data-equalizer');
    }
    else {
        // window width is less than 767px
        $('.row').removeAttr('data-equalizer');
    }

}
```

For some reason, I was not able to get this working

```
Foundation.utils.register_media('custom', "(min-width: 767px)");

if (matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries['custom']).matches) {
    // window width is at least 767px
    $('.row').attr('data-equalizer', 'data-equalizer');
} else {
    // window width is less than 767px
    $('.row').removeAttr('data-equalizer');
}
```

Preview : [@Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arvindravulavaru/mSdFN/show) | Code : [@Editor](http://jsfiddle.net/arvindravulavaru/mSdFN/)

~Arvind

Comment: Thanks for your response, I test it and remove data attributes in mobile. But data-equalizer still working.

Comment: I think we have to 'reflow' Equalizer after remove attr

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 6 supports a Equalizer property called "equalizeOn", which lets you set a breakpoint. Equalizer will do it's stuff to this breakpoint and up (Mobile First Approach).

Here's a link to the docs (Section, Plugin Options):
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html

You can set the option via data attributes in your HTML or via JavaScript.